# Facebook Graph API: Relationship status of Friends of Friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Running into an issue, which most likely is a permission thing with Facebook, but still worth asking on the forum. I'm able to successfully get the friends of the logged in / authorized user and can traverse the friends of that friend (if they've also installed the app).

So far, so good - however, I'm not able to peek at the relationship_status of the friends of friend - checked with the permission set and we seem to have the required perms as well.

The following are the perms I'm requesting from the user who signs up,for friends:
email,friends_relationships,friends_birthday,friends_about_me

Any ideas on what we might be missing? Am about to put this down to a per-user permission issue - but even friends with very low security don't have this attribute showing - which makes me feel that I'm missing some permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work as there is no extended permissions for friends of friends.  The only option would be to collect this information from the logged in user and their immediate friends, and then build this information up yourself as more people authenticate with your application, and then check to see what you know in your own database about friend of friends.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing this, slow burn though. I guess FB just doesn't reveal this information. Thanks.